# Minor trouble with AJAX POST method passing to C# MVC controller method

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, json

Hello denizens of stackoverflow, I've been debugging a pesky ajax POST method for a bit too long now, and was hoping I could get some input. I have a JavaScript function that collects an array of strings to box up and send off to a controller method of mine, but unfortunately the parameter data is not being sent, and I cannot figure out why.

**Here is the JS function:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'CancelDoc',
    method: 'POST',
    datatype: 'json',
    headers: addAntiForgeryHeader(),
    data: { datakeys : DataKeys }
}).done(function (data) {
    if (data.status == 0) {
        alert("DOCUMENT CANCELLED SUCCESSFULLY");
    }
});
```

**To clarify a little:**

`DataKeys` is the array of strings. It is coming through to this point as it should.
Looks something like:

```
["1432long-crazy4297-jumbled5826string|9000|1|1|NEW", 
"1432and2-another03-jumbled1594string|9000|1|1|NEW"]
```

`addAntiForgeryHeader()` is an extra client validation method that I add on to all POSTs. The problem should not lie here because I have commented this out to try the call and it still does not pass data.

**The C# controller method this goes to:**

Note: the code DOES make it this far, the `datakeys` parameter is `null` though.

```
public ActionResult CancelDoc(string[] datakeys)
{
    DocObject Doc = new DocObject();
    List<string> Datakeys = datakeys.ToList();

    foreach (var dk in Datakeys)
    {
        ...
        Some model logic here (not even making it here so no worries)
        ...
    }

    return Json(new { status = 0 });
}
```

**I have tried:**

- Data conversion to JSON in numerous ways: ko.mapping.toJS(data), JSON.stringify(data), and literal writing of a JSON object for this.
- Stripping the call down to the most basic form: I have tried commenting out the `datatype` and `headers` properties. This had a couple more properties before I posted as well.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've just tested your code and the array was passed to the action.
What version of MVC are you using?
I'm geussing the framework might having trouble binding the parameter but it does work in the latest version of MVC.

Comment: I pasted your code into a blank MVC app and the parameter had both `dataKeys`.  Are you sure `DataKeys` is populated when you get to your ajax request?

Comment: seems alrite to me. So, you did try data : {dataKeys: JSON.stringify(dataKeys)} ?

Comment: @Dev-One Okay, I missed that one. And turns out stringify-ing only the `DataKeys` variable packaged it up right. I may have to do some parsing on the controller, but that's fine by me. Thank you!

Comment: what is your asp.net mvc version? and can you show the http request?

Comment: so it worked? You would need to JSON.desearlizeObject(dataKeys) in the MVC controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataKeys payload need to be stringify as :

```
$.ajax({
    //prev code
    data: { datakeys : JSON.stringify(DataKeys) }
}).done(function (data) {
   //success
});
```

In the MVC controller, desearlze the json as:

```
public ActionResult CancelDoc(string[] datakeys)
{ 
    dynamic sourceJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(dataKeys, typeof(object));
    DocObject Doc = new DocObject();
    List<string> Datakeys = sourceJson.ToList();

}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks. The only thing I would say is that ToList() cannot be directly called on the sourceJson object. So changes I made for this to work were changing the typeof() from `object` to `string[]` and also replacing the List assignment line with `List<string> Datakeys = new List<string>(sourceJson);` Otherwise great answer!